# Is there a better way to resample time series stored into binary files in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, binary, resampling

I would like to resample time series stored into int32 binary files using Python.
I wrote down a function that does the trick; here's a simplified version of my function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

def resampleData(fileName_in,fileName_out,new_number_of_samples) 

    fIn = open(fileName_in, 'rb')
    data_in = np.fromfile(fIn, dtype="int32", count=-1, sep="")  
    fIn.close()

    data_out=signal.resample(data_in,new_number_of_samples).astype('int32')

    fOut = open(fileName_out, 'wb')
    data_out.tofile(fOut,sep="")
    fOut.close()

    return
```

When dealing with large files, my code takes a long time to run, which makes me wonder if there is a better solution. For instance, is there a built-in method allowing to directly resample time series stored into binary files without having to write them to a ndarray?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IO is the problem here since even for this big array:

```
np.empty(1000000000, 'i').tofile('abc.bin')
np.fromfile('abc.bin', 'i')
```

It only takes

```
1.18 s ± 26.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

to read it. If you insist, you can use `memmap`:

```
np.memmap('abc.bin', 'i')
```

which takes negligible time to "load", but will still have to do IO later:

```
5.6 µs ± 433 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

On the other hand, if by re-sampling you mean down-sampling, you can use the `memmap` method above and directly save slice of the orignal array like

```
memmap_result[::2].tofile('xxx')
```

which down samples by half.

If you need non-integer step down-sampling or you are up-sampling, and more importantly, you are fine with nearest neighbor method, you can use fancy indexing like:

```
memmap_result[np.linspace(0, len(memmap_result), num_samples).astype('i')]
```

which should also be fast.

For other cases, you might need to look for other re-sampling algorithms. I see `scipy.signal.resample` uses Fourier transform, which should be pretty fast and stable. You can use even faster algorithms like linear interpolation and etc. But the quality of re-sampling might be affected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ZislsNotZis! I will try using `memmap` to improve the computation time. Please note that I am not trying to downsample the time series, but to upsample the data from 500Hz to 512Hz.

Comment: Don't just downsample with `[::2]`. This might introduce [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) artifacts. `resample` takes care of such issues. `resample` can be very slow for certain input lengths because the FFT works best with certain composite numbered lengths. Zero-padding the input with the help of [`fftpack.next_fast_len`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html#scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len) should speed things up.

Comment: @kazemakase Wow the FFT fast len thing is definitly a useful and important thing to know (I never knew that). Thanks for sharing it! For the downsampling part, I thought aliasing is a image processing thing, while signal processing intends more to be accurate (like what's the value at some exact second)?

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis Aliasing is an issue with all discrete signals. Prior to (down)sampling all frequency components higher than half the new sampling rate need to be removed. Otherwise they are folded into the sampling range and contaminate whatever is already there.